# Matrix algebra operation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have matrix as below:

$\begin{bmatrix} a&b&c\\d&e&f\end{bmatrix}$

how can I get matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix} a/a&b/(a+b)&c/(a+b+c)\\d/d&e/(d+e)&f/(d+e+f)\end{bmatrix}$

I can use only matrix algebra operation.

Comment: What if $a=1, b=-1$?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: write the equation
$$
\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x_{11}&x_{12}&x_{13}\\x_{21}&x_{22}&x_{23}\\x_{31}&x_{32}&x_{33}\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} a/a&b/(a+b)&c/(a+b+c)\\d/d&e/(d+e)&f/(d+e+f)\end{bmatrix}
$$
and solve the linear system in $x_{ij}$. Good luck.